# Conditionally remove elements from a List in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8

As far as I know Java 8 introduces a new method available for Collection types: removeif(). It accepts a predicate which defines the condition on which the elements should be removed. It returns a boolean where a true response means that at least one item has been removed and false otherwise:
I have this class:

```
HotelPriceSummary {
     Hotel hotel;
     float price
}
```

a `List<HotelPriceSummary> allHotels;`

and `Iterable<Hotel> discardedHotels`

I would like to do something like (obviously **existsIn** is a functions that does not exist, is to express what I would like to do but I didn't find the way)

```
allHotels.removeIf(h -> h.getHotel().existsIn (discardedHotels))
```

Comment: You can produce a `HashSet` from the `discardedHotels` Iterable (assuming `Hotel` overrides equals and hashCode) and use `set.contains()`

Comment: Could you get by using a `Collection` instead of an `Iterable`?  It would make this much simpler.

Comment: use `ArrayList.removeAll(Collection<?> c)`

Comment: How about `discardedHotels.forEach(h -> allHotels.removeIf(hps -> hps.getHotel().equals(h)))`? Not very efficient, I know.

Comment: @Harshit There's no `ArrayList`, no `Collection`, and they're not even the same element type.

Comment: How did you get your Iterable ?

Comment: @Harshit it won't work objects are of different types. How Hotel will be compared to HotelPriceSummary?

Comment: @shmosel, works like a charm. Please convert to answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't efficiently locate an item in an `Iterable`. I would suggest copying it to a temporary set (unless it already is a set) and then calling `contains()`:

```
Set<Hotel> discardedSet = new HashSet<>();
discardedHotels.forEach(discardedSet::add);
allHotels.removeIf(h -> discardedSet.contains(h.getHotel()));
```

If you don't mind the O(n*m) complexity, you can call `List.removeIf()` within `Iterable.forEach()`:

```
discardedHotels.forEach(h -> allHotels.removeIf(hps -> hps.getHotel().equals(h)))
```

Comment: Set creation can be simplified by `Set<Hotel> discardedSet = StreamSupport.stream(discardedHotels.spliterator(), false).collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Comment: @Flown Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't see that as a simplification.